# Run chrome in device mode without activating debugger

Tags: ionic2, visual-studio-code, google-chrome-devtools

I'm using VS Code to develop an Ionic 2 app and using it's chrome debugging extension to step through the code within VS Code. Being an Ionic app, I primarily want to run it in device mode to simulate mobile device, but when I open the Dev Tools window Chrome's internal debugger automatically connects and breaks the connection with VS Code. It's really annoying that those two functions are connected with each other. Regardless, is there a way to work around this?

Comment: AFAIK it's only implemented in [blisk](https://blisk.io/), a webdev-related fork of chromium.

Comment: @wOxxOm this is as close to an answer as I've found. Thanks! Blisk did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

According to this VS forum post, https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/2828/vs-2017-rc1-cant-disable-chrome-debugging-support.html, "It looks like they added an option in Debugging > General called Enable Javascript debugging for ASP.NET (Chrome and IE) to disable this. I think this report can be closed."

Disclamer: I copied that quote from the forum post and have no intention of plagirism.

Comment: Thanks for that, but it appears the information is specific to Visual Studio 2017 and also doesn't actually answer the question of how to disable Chrome's internal debugger. I'm looking for how to disable Chrome's debugger while using VS Code.